# External Web page is not loading everytime in htmlagility pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am using htmlagilitypack to scrape some part of a webpage. I am getting the actual output but not always.

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb(); 
web.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.0.4) Gecko/20060508 Firefox/1.5.0.4";
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);
var resultPriceTable = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='resultsset']//table");
```

resultPriceTable is coming as null in some cases(nearly 50%).From debugging I found that

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);
```

is causing issue. It sometimes not loading the url. How to fix this issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try load your page via WebClient or HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse and then send result to HtmlAgilityPack

this code sample try to download page up to 5 time if you get empty string or get `WebException`

*in production code don't simply skip exceptions, you need to handle it carefully (or at least log it)*

***Sample:***

```
string html = string.Empty;
            int tries = 5;
            while (tries > 0)
            {
                using (var client = new WebClient())
                {

                    string url = "http://google.com/";
                    client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.0.4) Gecko/20060508 Firefox/1.5.0.4");
                    try
                    {
                       html = client.DownloadString(url);
                        tries--;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(html))
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (WebException)
                    {
                        tries--;
                    }
                }
            }
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(html);
```

Comment: Thank you Alexander.If I am using this, I am getting html ="" most of the time.

Comment: looks like an issue with server that host page, try to increase number of tries